Make a service execute only once when a component is created
A service is created containing two integers to increment:

The first variable, outerCounter, needs to be incremented once and only once when the component is first rendered. Even if the component gets destroyed, then gets re-rendered, it shouldn't increment.
The second variable, innerCounter, should start at 1 and then increment the component whenever needed.

In other words, outerCounter needs to be shared among all of the components and gets incremented once when a component is rendered once or n times, whereas innerCounter is not shared and is incremented independently of the complement.
For convenience, I have created a StackBlitz project. It has three different components and the required result is to have 1.1 for the first component, 2.1 for the second component and 3.1 for the last component. In case there inner counter is incremented in another tag, then it will be 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, etc in the first component, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4, etc. in the second component and 3.2, 3.3, 3.4, etc. in the last component. Any assistance would be appreciated!

can we have multiple service instances?

@NarenMurali, Sure!

I think, you can handleouterCounter with ngAfterViewInit(). In every component (one, two and three) you call incrementOuterCounter from the service class in their ngAfterviewInit()

We can use a service, that contains two objects outerCounterMap and innerCounterMap their job is to store the counter, based on the component name.
The only special condition is that, we can only increment the outer counter only once, when the value is set to zero.
 incrementOuterCounter(className: string): void {
    if (!this.outerCounterMap[className]) {
      this.outerCounterMap[className] = 0;
    }
    if (this.outerCounterMap[className] === 0) { // update only once!
      this.internalInnerCounter++;
      this.outerCounterMap[className] = this.internalInnerCounter;
    }
  }

Now, we can use this.constructor.name to get the component name, to track the indexes based on this name, as the key to the maps of the service(outerCounterMap and innerCounterMap). This will generate the desired output.
Full Code:
one.component.ts
import { AfterViewInit, Component, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { CounterService } from '../../services/counter.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-one',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [],
  templateUrl: './one.component.html',
  styleUrl: './one.component.css',
})
export class OneComponent {
  className: string = this.constructor.name;
  label: string = '';
  constructor(public counter: CounterService) {
    this.counter.incrementOuterCounter(this.className);
    this.counter.incrementInnerCounter(this.className);
  }

  getLabel() {
    return (
      this.counter.getOuterCounter(this.className) +
      '.' +
      this.counter.getInnerCounter(this.className)
    );
  }
}

service.ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class CounterService {
  private outerCounterMap: { [key: string]: number } = {};
  private innerCounterMap: { [key: string]: number } = {};
  internalInnerCounter = 0;
  constructor() {}

  getInnerCounter(className: string): number {
    return this.innerCounterMap[className] || 0;
  }

  incrementInnerCounter(className: string): void {
    if (!this.innerCounterMap[className]) {
      this.innerCounterMap[className] = 0;
    }
    this.innerCounterMap[className] = this.innerCounterMap[className] + 1;
  }

  getOuterCounter(className: string): number {
    return this.outerCounterMap[className] || 0;
  }
  incrementOuterCounter(className: string): void {
    if (!this.outerCounterMap[className]) {
      this.outerCounterMap[className] = 0;
    }
    if (this.outerCounterMap[className] === 0) {
      this.internalInnerCounter++;
      this.outerCounterMap[className] = this.internalInnerCounter;
    }
  }
}

Stackblitz Demo

Thank you for the answer. The inner counter will keep on incrementing if the button is kept on being pressed. In the example provided, all should have the inner counter as 1, since one paragraph is created. In case there are multiple paragraphs, then it should increase to x.2, x.3, etc.. The out counter is working as expected.

@M.AlJumaily It's not possible to do this, because there is no way to differentiate between component rendering inside a @if or @for and component just rendering without conditionals

A solution using 2 service instances:
@Injectable({
    providedIn: "root"
})
export class Counter {

    private _counter = 0;

    increment() {
       this._counter++;
    }

    get counter(): number {
       return this._counter;
    }
}

The component using the counters:

import { Counter } from './counter';
...

@Component({
    templateUrl: '....',
    standalone: true,
    imports[ ... ],
    providers: [
       Counter
    }
})
export class MyComponent {
    innerCounter = inject(Counter); // the instance provided by this component
    outerCounter = inject(Counter, { skipSelf: true }); // the instance provided in root

    ....
}

